# How to control the alignment of the brace in a dcases environment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, cases, mathtools

The following code

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        u = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(i+j)\\
        v = k
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
```

results in the following display
[image: Go home, equation, you're ugly.]
that I find particularly disgraceful. Is there a way to lower the brace to make it look more like this
[image: Much better-looking equation]
?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "smash" the fraction from the top using `\smash[t]`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        u = \smash[t]{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(i+j)}\\
        v = k
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

The command `\smash[b]` would be useful for the last line.

---

Workaround: since I don't suppose you need it regularly, a manual tweak suggested by [egreg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7199845#7199845) is possible. Here, we increase the vertical space above the equation, and by grouping we ensure that the effect will be local.

```
\begingroup\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{4pt}\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        u = \smash[t]{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}(i+j)\\
        v = k
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}\endgroup
```

Comment: This has some small inconveniences: the vertical placement of the equation will not take into account the smashed fraction, so it can end too near the preceding line.

Comment: @egreg Actually, the `[t]` option only smashes the top part, so there is no such issue.

Comment: @Evpok The issue *is* there: the square root is placed too near the line preceding the display, for my tastes.

Comment: @egreg Oh, sorry, I misread your comment. Reader from the future: the aforementionned chat is at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7199794#7199794